# WordPress Instagram feed plugin

Tags: wordpress, instagram

My client is looking for a WordPress Instagram plugin that has the "Load More" functionality similar to the Instagram site itself.

[image: 'Load more' button under some images]

So when you click on "load more" the next set of images are displayed.

We are currently using the [Enjoy Plugin for Instagram](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/enjoy-instagram-instagram-responsive-images-gallery-and-carousel/) which has a nice grid, but I was just wondering if anyone knows of a plugin that also has a "load more" feature so I don't have to take the time to modify the current plugin we are using.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Instagram Feed WD](https://web-dorado.com/products/wordpress-instagram-feed-wd.html) and [Instagram Feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/instagram-feed/) have the "load more" button. Here is a quick preview of the first one:

[image]

and here is the preview for the second one:

[image]